# How to mentain navigation stack in html

Tags: html, navigation, stack

```
    i have several pages in in my application
    suppose 
    a.html,b.html,c.html
```

and user can navigate from one page to another frequently but when user want to go back and when it click to cancle button he should be automatically redirect to the previous page which was accessed by him.is there any solution for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you simply want to emulate the browser's `back` button. This can be done with javascript:

```
window.history.back();
```

Comment: can it preserves the state of previous pag?